# Validating changes to a column in a datatable depending on another column

Tags: vb.net, validation, datatable, multiple-columns

I'm working in VB.net in Visual Studio 2008.

I'm trying to add validation to a databound dataSet. 
So far, I have been doing simple validation by handling the "ColumnChanging" event of the dataSet.
This is done almost entirely for me by double clicking on a dataColumn in the dataSet:

```
If (e.Column.ColumnName = Me.nameColumn.ColumnName) Then
    If e.ProposedValue.ToString.Trim = "" Then
        e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "You must provide a name for this person.")
    Else
        e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "")
    End If
End If
```

This works well for simple validation for fields that don't depend on any other fields.

I would like to conditionally validate columns differently depending on the values of other columns in the dataSet.

For example, say I have a "driver" table that stores info about how drivers drive their cars.

It would include fields:

```
personID (Foreign Key to the "person" table)
vehicleTypeID (Foreign Key to the "vehicleType" table)
percentHighway
percentCity
wheelCount
```

I would like to validate that:

1) percentHighway and percentCity add up to 100

-If they do not, call SetColumnError for both columns

2) wheelCount > 4 when vehicleTypeID = 3 (meaning the vehicle is a Semi Truck, rather than a Car or Pickup Truck)

-If it does not, setColumnError for vehicleTypeID and wheelCount

EDIT:

All right, as @jmcilhinney pointed out below, I can use e.Row to access the row data. Then from there, I can see the other columns with:

```
e.Row.Item("columnName")
```

Now I'm looking to add errors to multiple columns at once. I can say:

```
e.Row.SetColumnError("columnName", "Error Message")
```

and that works fine, but only for the column that is currently being changed.

If I say:

```
e.Row.SetColumnError("columnName1", "Error Message 1")
e.Row.SetColumnError("columnName2", "Error Message 2")
```

Only ONE of those errors will actually be created, and only ONE control on my databound form will pop up a ! to show an error. Only the field that is being changed actually gets an error message added to it.

Thank you for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your code has access to the row via the e.Row property.  You can get any field value you want from that row and do whatever you want with it, including use it in validating other fields.

Comment: Once you pointed that out, I was able to get much farther.


`e.ProposedValue`
-gives me the value of the changing column.


`e.Row.Item("columnName")`
-gives me the value of a different column.


Now I'm trying to figure out adding errors.
`e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "Error Message")`
-sets the error for the current changing column. The error provider on the databound form beeps and boops appropriately.


I thought I might be able to raise errors on the other related column with:
`e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Row.Table.Columns("columnName"), "")`
but that doesn't seem to work